# cmake add external already-built library

Tags: c++, cmake

I would like to add a dependency to a target. This dependency is a precompiled lib. I would like to be able to get a external dependency just by specifing a name like `add_dep(libName)` in my `CMakeLists.txt`. The `add_dep` function should be reusable for different libraries.

I couldn't find any way to do this, [only for libs which are compiled during build](https://rix0r.nl/blog/2015/08/13/cmake-guide/)

[how would I pass the target name in a generic form here?](https://community.kde.org/Frameworks/Epics/CMake_target_usage_requirements)

[would be fine, but the "consumer" shouldn't have to add inc/lib dirs etc](https://ecrafter.wordpress.com/2012/06/16/cmake-tutorial-part-5/).

Comment: It seems like you want an [imported library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries), which then can be used as normal by [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: And how would I do that? Add a lib.cmake file to a common dir. But I do not want to include anything, it would be ok to do a call like `find_package(libName)` + `target_link_libraries(libName)`, but no idea how that should work...
or would it be added to a root cmake file and is therefore available on the whole project?

Comment: @user9601767: Could you add some code, which describes what you have? It is not clear, what exactly `add_dep` should do. And your comment with `I do not want to include anything` isn't clear too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude):

In the dir of the external lib `CMakeList.txt`:

```
find_library(lib libName dir/to)
add_library(libName SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL) # GLOBAL -> if outside src tree
set_property(TARGET libName PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${lib})
set_property(TARGET libName APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

in the "root" `CMakeList.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory("$ENV{COMMON_ROOT}/libs/libName" "$ENV{COMMON_ROOT}/libs/libName") # usage for out of src ref
```

add `target_link_libraries(target libName)` to the `CMakeLists.txt` who needs it.

Answer (score 0):

CMake gives an excellent [tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/using-dependencies/index.html#guide:Using%20Dependencies%20Guide) about adding dependencies into a build. The good old `find_package()` is used to incorporate dependencies that have been built locally (by either CMake or other build systems), while the relatively new (since CMake 3.11) [`FetchContent`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) is able to download source code with CMake support and build the dependencies within the build folder (more like `npm install` and `package.json` for JavaScript).

However, building from sources can be time-consuming, especially for some big libraries, such as [Boost](https://github.com/boostorg/boost), and you may want to first search for locally built libraries before resorting to the source code. The good news is that you can have the best of both worlds by integrating `FetchContent` and `find_package()` with the `FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS` option of `FetchContent_Declare()`. This allows CMake to try calling `find_packge()` first to satisfy the dependency, and then build from the source if the target is absent. You can also enforce the build-from-source policy if you want to control the version (or a specific commit) of the dependency with the `OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE` option.

Here is a small example project covering my frequently used third-party libraries: [`Eigen`](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/tree/master?ref_type=heads) and [`fmt`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt). If you have already built the libraries locally (e.g., via Homebrew on macOS), it will be as fast as using `find_package()`.

#### Files

Within one folder:

- `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
set(PROJECT_NAME test)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

# For FetchContent_Declare() and FetchContent_MakeAvailable()
include(FetchContent)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Eigen
FetchContent_Declare(Eigen
  GIT_REPOSITORY git@gitlab.com:libeigen/eigen.git
  GIT_TAG 3147391d # Release 3.4.0
  FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS NAMES Eigen3
)

# fmt
FetchContent_Declare(fmt
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git
  GIT_TAG f5e5435 # Release 10.1.1
  FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS NAMES fmt
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Eigen fmt)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Eigen3::Eigen fmt::fmt)
```

- `main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  // Eigen
  Eigen::Vector3d coords{1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
  std::cout << "Vec = " << coords << std::endl;
  // fmt
  fmt::print("Hello world and!\n");
}
```

#### Build

1. Within the same folder, create a `build` subfolder:

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

2. Run `cmake`

```
cmake ..
```

3. Run `make`

```
make
```

Comment: [`GIT_TAG` docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html): "_In general, however, specifying a commit hash should be preferred for a number of reasons \[...\]_"

Comment: Nice catch! Specifying a commit hash or a git tag corresponding to a release version should be preferred for better version control. I have edited the answer to clarify this point. Also, I have removed the Boost dependency since people normally use individual components (e.g., `filesystem`, `graph`, etc.) instead of the full library. In the case of Boost, we should use `find_package(Boost REQUIRED filesystem graph)` to only select necessary dependencies.

Comment: Now that I read the doc, I fully agree that using a git hash is better than a git tag for production code due to performance and traceability considerations. Answer edited.

Comment: Yes. As long as a tag is stable, it is good too. For some development branches or the latest release branch, the HEAD commit may change frequently, and therefore a git hash is preferred. I think the performance concern still applies to stable git tags, because CMake will run `git fetch` to check for possible changes unless you set a git hash.